# In R - How to subset data using ID as a vector argument in function?

Tags: r

So, I've created the following code that gets me the mean of a series of rows having the same ID, so if I input pollutemean(directory,pollutant,id) i get a numeric result, however, if I input the a vector identifying more than one ID, i.e: 1:18 as here pollutemean(directory,pollutant,1:15), the code breaks. How can I have it working for both options?

CODE:

```
pollutemean <- function(directory,pollutant,id)  {
    alldata <- lapply(list.files(directory, full.names=TRUE),read.csv,header=TRUE)
    alldatamerged<-do.call(rbind,alldata)

        if (pollutant=="sulfate") {
          allsulfatedata <- alldatamerged[c("Date","sulfate","ID")]
          allsulfatedatabyid<-allsulfatedata[allsulfatedata$"ID"==id,]
          completesulfatedatabyid<-na.omit(allsulfatedatabyid)
          print(mean(completesulfatedatabyid$sulfate))
        }
```

OUTPUT:

> pollutemean("specdata","sulfate",8)
>   [1] 4.781354
>   pollutemean("specdata","sulfate",1:8)
>   [1] 4.252498
>   Warning message:
>   In allsulfatedata$ID == id :
>     longer object length is not a multiple of shorter object length

Comment: You should discuss your problem in the Coursera forum...

Comment: @Eloy Giles Use `%in%` instead of `==`. Also, it is better to use `[` for subsetting in place of `$`

Comment: A typo:  `alldatamerged[c("Date","sulfate","ID")]`  should be  `alldatamerged[,c("Date","sulfate","ID")]`

Comment: @PeterDee, yep, had posted this already in the forum.

Comment: @akrun Only changing `==` to `%in%` is not enough! EDIT: My mistake, i thought the code was  `id %in% allsulfatedata$"ID" `

Comment: @FrancescoPalmiotto  I was giving some ideas.  I didn't check the full function.  The one obvious thing I commented.  If there are other issues, you could mention that in your answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
allsulfatedatabyid<-allsulfatedata[allsulfatedata$ID %in% id, ]
```

Or:

```
allsulfatedatabyid<-allsulfatedata[id[which(id %in% allsulfatedata$ID)], ]
```